# Person – недопустимый тип целевого объекта для свойства publisher

Tags: html, seo

Вот страница

https://keyua.org/blog/fixed-price/

Проверяю её в гугл валидаторе

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=ru

. Доку прочитал, но так и не понял, что ему не нравится...

> Person – недопустимый тип целевого объекта для свойства publisher.

Что-то не так в этой части

```
<div itemprop="publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="col-md-3"><meta itemprop="name" content="Igor Zats"/><div class="content hidden-block"><div class="content-title">CONTENTS</div><div class="js-table-content"><ul></ul></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное содержание указанной вами веб-страницы представляет статья, с автором таким как персона **Igor Zats** и организацию издателя такую как **KeyUA inc**.

Однако, **[структурированные данные это веб-страницы](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fkeyua.org%2Fblog%2Ffixed-price%2F)** имеют разметку для издателя (тип **Организация**) с названием таким как **Igor Zats**. 
Таким образом, ваши структурированные данные для этой веб-страницы, ссылаются на скрытое от пользователей содержание, что явялется **[сигналом спама для Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175)**:

> **С помощью структурированных данных размечен скрытый контент**
>
> Структурированные данные обнаружены в элементах, которые не видны
>   пользователям. Это противоречит нашим правилам.

Кроме того, ваши данные созданы в формате **микродата**, который устанавливается прямо в исходный код HTML. Поэтому, может быть полезным проверить **[следующую ошибку исходного кода этой веб-страницы](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fkeyua.org%2Fblog%2Ffixed-price%2F)**, которая связана с вашими данными:

> Error: Element meta is missing required attribute content.
>
> From line 6, column 6; to line 6, column 133
>
> it?↩

```
</h1><meta itemscope itemprop="**mainEntityOfPage**"
> itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage"
> itemid="https://keyua.org/blog/fixed-price/"/>
```

Свойство **publisher**, ваших данных, вложено внутрь типа **mainEntityOfPage**, который имеет вышеуказанную ошибку. Поэтому есть вероятность того, что эта ошибка оказывает влияние на весь блок ваших данных вложенных в этот тип.

Смею предположить, что ваш вопрос имеет отношение, скорее к валидности вашей разметки, чем к структурированным данным. Поэтому, я рекомендую вам с подобными вопросами обращаться в **[справочный форум сообщества для веб-мастеров Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/community)**.